# When is $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n]$ a Euclidean Domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, roots-of-unity, principal-ideal-domains, euclidean-domain

After having accidentally duplicated [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496320/when-is-bbbz-zeta-n-a-pid), I thought I'd follow up with a related question.  In an answer to the linked question, Zev Chonoles quotes the first page of Chapter 11 of Washington's *[Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields](https://books.google.com/books?id=KBgDCAAAQBAJ&q=Chapter+11#v=snippet&q=Chapter%2011&f=false)* which states that the only $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n]$ with $\zeta_n$ a root of unity that are [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain)s (with class number 1) are extensions with the following values of $n$:

```
 1,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  
 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16,
17, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25,
27, 28, 32, 33, 35, 36,
40, 44, 45, 48, 60, 84.
```

In addition, values of $n \equiv 2 \mod 4$ are also allowed, because for example, $\mathbb Z[\zeta_{30}] = \mathbb Z[\zeta_{15}]$.  So my question is, which are known to be Euclidean Domains?  I'm especially interested if $n = 60$ admits a form of the Euclidean division algorithm.

Comment: @hurkyl Good catch.  I've edited the question.

Comment: @Hurkyl I suspect what is meant is the ring of integers of those fields.  While $\mathbb Z[\zeta_n]$ is certainly contained in the ring of integers, can you confirm that the containment is actually equality?

Comment: @Aaron https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17289/quick-proof-of-the-fact-that-the-ring-of-integers-of-q-zeta-n-is-z-zeta-n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have the following Theorem, see [here](http://algant.eu/documents/theses/simachew.pdf), Theorem $5.2$ on page 50:

**Theorem 5.2.** A cyclotomic field is Euclidean if and only if it is principal ideal domain.

So this leads again back to the duplicate question.

Comment: Seems I can't win.  Oh well, it's good to know that in this case these cyclotomic fields are both PIDs and Euclidean Domains.

Comment: The thesis you reference, Theorem 5.2, rests his conclusion on Weinberger's result which is, of course, conditional on GRH.  An unconditional proof of the result that *A cyclotomic field is Euclidean if and only if it is principal ideal domain* appears in Harper, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$ is Euclidean, https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-2004-003-9

Comment: @Malcolm Yes, I know. I wanted to cite Harper's result, I am sorry.